# Can't send data to the Controller with a POST method Symfony3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a POST method Jquery. Ajax and I can't send my data to the controller, I have tried every solution on the net, but no result.......

My JavaScript

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submitForm').click(function(){

            var data1 = {request : $('#request').val()};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Manufacturer",
                data: data1,
                success: function(dataBack) {
                    console.log(dataBack);

                },
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        });
    });
```

MY controller

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    //$name = $request->request->get('data');
    //return new Response($name);//or do whatever you want with the sent value
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        $name = $request->request->get('data1');
        If($name == 1)
        {
            return new Response('Yeap');
        }
        else
        {
            return new Response(';(');
        }

    }
    return $this->render('MyIndex/Manufacturer_LIST.html.twig' );
}
```

HEre is my Console ::

And my response is as it's obvious ";("

Comment: Search for symfony post json payload.  Lots of answers.  You need something like: $data = json_decode($request->getContent(),true);

Comment: Thanks for the answer Cerad, I was wondering if  $data = $request->request->get('data1');  data1= should match  data1: data in the Ajax method

Comment: $request->request only works for form encoded data, not json payloads.  Common error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to install FOSJsRoutingBundle to be able to "expose" your Symfony routes into the javascript code. Follow the steps in the official documentation.

Then, in your twig template if you have a form like:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name"> <br>
    <button type="submit" id="submitForm">Submit</button>
</form>
```

your js code could look liks this:

```
$('#submitForm').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: Routing.generate('Manufacturer_LIST');
        // OR: url: "/Manufacturer", if you don't want to install FOSJsRoutingBundle
        data: { name:name }
    }).done(function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    }).fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
    });
});
```

And in your controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/Manufacturer", name="Manufacturer_LIST", options={"expose"=true})
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request){
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        $name = $request->request->get('name');
        return new Response($name);//or do whatever you want with the sent value
    }
    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}
```

Comment: FOSJsRoutingBundle is not necessary, you can write the route path inside js like this : `url: "{{ path('the_path') }}",`

Comment: Yeah, but FOSJeRoutingBundle looks more profi to me. And a matter of taste.

Comment: Dan Costinel Thanks for your answer, but when I try to submit the data, it redirect me to my Manufacturer page, there is no data in the controller

Comment: @Metio_1993 If you still using your old code, then I guess this line of code is wrong: `data1: data`.  I think you need to revert those names as `data: data1`, and in plus add: `var data1 = {request : $('#request').val()};`. And please notice that `e.preventDefault();` statement, which tells the browser not take the browser to the new URL, specified by `url:`.

Comment: I edit my Question, My idea is to sent the data1 value to the controller and check if the value is equal to 1.... I really don't know where is the problem ...

Comment: @Metio_1993 I think the problem is your js code. Use my js code EXACTLY as is (you can use also that `url: "/Manufacturer"` route), and in your controller you can test as you'd wish. Fe., I just tested out your expectations, and I got the right answer. `$name = $request->request->get('name'); if($name == 1){ return new Response('Yeap'); } else { return new Response(':('); }`. I got 'Yeap'.

Comment: Dan Costinel, Thanks for the help, I go it working the problem was in the Ajax code, so I'll vote for your answer, the problem was I was not sending data properly....